# Why was the var keyword not dropped from Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I've recently started looking at Typescript syntax. I like the more concise syntax and it feels more grown-up with support for interfaces, classes and modules.

However, when looking at variable declaration, I cannot figure out why instead of:

`var x: number = 1;`

They did not choose the syntax:

`x: number = 1;`

Why keep the `var` keyword?

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript; it merely adds syntax which is compiled to JavaScript. From [the source](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf): "TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a superset of Ecmascript 5 (ES5) syntax." So it's not going to diverge from basic JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Because [typescript is a superset of javascript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf) it is only additative and so cannot 'drop' language features that are already defined in the Ecmascript 5 syntax.

So var is here to stay.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript; it merely adds syntax which is compiled to JavaScript. From [the source](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Content/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.pdf): "TypeScript is a syntactic sugar for JavaScript. TypeScript syntax is a superset of Ecmascript 5 (ES5) syntax." So it's not going to diverge from basic JavaScript syntax.